# how to remove jar file from project?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, manifest

I have big project in java. Project packages have its on `lib` folder for certain dependency.
Now Its size is grown.

In some pkg's `lib` contain two jars those are almost identical.

like `abc/lib` has `commons-lang-2.5 jar.`

and  `xyz/lib` has `commons-lang-2.6 jar.`

Now I think its adding some redundency so what I do to have simple one jar only.

so which one I remove? and how do I manage Manifest.inf eclipse file?

Answer (score 2):

What type of Eclipse project are you working with? If it is a regular Eclipse Java project you can right click on the project in the project explorer and edit the settings, i.e. remove the JAR from the project. It will no longer be in the project classpath. You will then see it popping up as a file. Deleting it from the the sructure will remove the file from the file system.

If it is a Plug-in, OSGi, project just double click on the manifest file and edit it using the Manifest-editor, which is opened by default. Click on the runtime tab and remove the JAR from the list of JARs and it will no longer be on the bundle classpath. Same as above, deleting the file will have it removed from the structure.

Which one of the commons-lang JARs to remove? Well, it depends; what does your code require? I would say go with the highest stable version. But, make sure that it is what you actually need.